# ModuleNotFoundErr while run python script with jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

The python script can be run successfully on node machine, but run it with jenkins pipeline, will notify `ModuleNotFoundError`.

pipeline script:

```
stage('Prepare'){
        options { timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES')  }
        agent {label 'NUC_05'} /* <-------------- */
        steps{
            script{
                t_rv=nodesByLabel('NUC_05')
                if (t_rv.size()==0) error "Host: NUC_05 is offline"
            }
            /*error "debug to stop here."*/
            dir('C:\\workspace\\work\\preparetestbench'){ 
                echo "Prepare pipeline info"
                bat "py -3 preparetest.py"
            }
        }
    }
```

Log:
C:\workspace\preparetestbench>py -3 preparetest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "preparetest.py", line 28, in 
import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

Comment: Did you install all dependencies on the jenkins server ?

Comment: no,  you mean also need install the dependencies on jenkins server ?   actually,  the python script can can successfully on node machine,  it seems that can't find the dependencies path while running with jenkins pipeline

Comment: Indeed, Jenkins out of the box has no idea how to run Python or look for its dependencies. A common solution is to have the pipeline set up a virtual environment and `pip install -r requirements.txt` after checking out the project, or something like that. (A virtual environment is helpful because it allows you to have different dependencies for different builds, and helps keep the configuration of the build nodes simple and obvious.)

Comment: @tripleee, thanks you so much. I have found the reason as module package path is not as my expection. usually the package path is C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages after installed (already set python install for all users), but on my machine , the package path is C:\Users\NUC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages, I don't know why .

Comment: There are about a dozen different reasons your Python package path is not what you expect; probably a duplicate of one of them, but without more details, we can't really say which one.